# Error message when using openpyxl.load_workbook() function

Tags: python, excel

I have just started to learn programming and I am currently trying to read an excel file from IDLE. I'm following instruction from the book "Automate the Boring Stuff". I have successfully imported openpyxl, and thereafter, as instructed tried `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')` where I exchanged "example" to the actual name of the workbook. However, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 117, in load_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1216, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jan.xlsx'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('jan.xlsx')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 145, in load_workbook
    raise InvalidFileException(unicode(e))
openpyxl.exceptions.InvalidFileException: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jan.xlsx'
```

I don't understand how to solve this.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Is jan.xlsx in the working directory? I think path of file might be wrong.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar That is all the code I have written. I just wanted to test that the instructions in "automate the boring stuff" worked. And there's something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This error message simply says that python can't locate the file. When you try to open a file 'jan.xlsx', it's trying to locate it in the base directory of your code in your IDE. So say your code is in a directory called /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myCode
(I'm assuming here you are on a Mac OS as the path to your python suggests...

but jan.xlsx is in /Users/username

Since that is 2 directories up from your code directory, you can do one of two things:

1. Write in the absolute path to the file:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/username/jan.xlsx')
```

2. Use a relative path that is relative to the base project directory. Two dots in a relative path means one level up from the current directory. So if the excel file is 2 levels up, you can do:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('../../jan.xlsx')
```

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. If you wanted me to use exactly what you wrote there, "wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/username/jan.xlsx')" that didn't work. Or maybe I was supposed to change somethings in there, as I said, I'm so new that I understand I might look very stupid for most of you here, and I'm sorry about that, but seriously, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: @AlicePettersson no worries, we all start at the beginning. If you are indeed on a Mac (this differs greatly on different operating systems), then try following this: http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/05/copy-file-path-name-text-mac-os-x-finder/ to get the full path to your jan.xlsx. Apple makes it annoyingly difficult to get the full path. But try that... In Finder window, right-click on jan.xlsx. Then while still in that menu, hold down OPTION button, and then select "Copy jan.xlsx as Pathname". Then go into your code, and paste that inside the single quotes in your call to load_workbook

Comment: I fixed it finally, thanks to a friend. Thank you for the time and energy you put into helping me.